# No duplication of code in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a problem on my sql statement. It must have no duplicate on my symbol codes. How I will the removed the other symbol codes with duplicates?

```
 SELECT     TOP (10) dbo.ltb_stockinfo.**SymbolCode**, dbo.stockInfoPrices.ChangePercent
 FROM       dbo.ltb_stockinfo INNER JOIN
            dbo.stockInfoPrices ON dbo.ltb_stockinfo.ID = dbo.stockInfoPrices.SymbolListId
WHERE     (dbo.ltb_stockinfo.NSCMarketSegment = N'NO')
GROUP BY dbo.ltb_stockinfo.SymbolCode, dbo.stockInfoPrices.ChangePercent
ORDER BY dbo.stockInfoPrices.ChangePercent DESC
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use max, min will work or even sum

```
SELECT     TOP (10) dbo.ltb_stockinfo.SymbolCode, MAX(dbo.stockInfoPrices.ChangePercent)
 FROM       dbo.ltb_stockinfo INNER JOIN
            dbo.stockInfoPrices ON dbo.ltb_stockinfo.ID = dbo.stockInfoPrices.SymbolListId
WHERE     (dbo.ltb_stockinfo.NSCMarketSegment = N'NO')
GROUP BY dbo.ltb_stockinfo.SymbolCode
ORDER BY MAX(dbo.stockInfoPrices.ChangePercent) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 dbo.ltb_stockinfo.SymbolCode, ...`